# Passing DateTime Lists to Oracle Stored Procedure C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, list, stored-procedures

I have been given the task of passing start dates and end dates into an orcale procedure from aspx/c# page.  I have 2 lists of DateTime objects on the page, a list of start dates and a list of end dates.

My question is how should I go about doing this? I believe I will have to create a user defined type to pass to the procedure, probably as a 2d array, but I'm really not sure how to:

A. Populate the array with the values from the 2 lists, and:

B. Create a user defined type to pass to the procedure.

I've done a bit of digging around but there are not many good examples of this, and I'm not even sure if i'm on the right track.  I would appreciate any help as I am really struggling to get my head around this.  I have included the oracle pl/sql code below (this cannot be changed as I do not have the ability to make ammendments):

```
PROCEDURE p_add_project_dates(

p_project_id IN CS01_PROJECT_HEADER.PROJECT_ID%TYPE,

p_tab_project_dates IN t_tab_project_dates,

   p_any_time_participation IN CS01_PROJECT_HEADER.ANY_TIME_PARTICIPATION%TYPE,

   p_error_msg OUT VARCHAR2,

p_return_code OUT NUMBER

) IS

occur_added_retcode NUMBER := 0;

   occur_added_message VARCHAR2(500);

BEGIN

p_return_code := 0;

-- Update ANY_TIME_PARTICIPATION.

UPDATE CS01_PROJECT_HEADER

   SET ANY_TIME_PARTICIPATION = p_any_time_participation

   WHERE PROJECT_ID = p_project_id;

   -- Add project occurrence for every record in p_tab_project_dates.

FOR i IN 1 .. p_tab_project_dates.COUNT LOOP

     CS02_PCK.p_add_project_occurrence(p_project_id, p_tab_project_dates(i).start_date, p_tab_project_dates(i).end_date, occur_added_message, occur_added_retcode);

     IF occur_added_retcode = 20 THEN

       p_return_code := 20;

          EXIT;

     END IF;

   END LOOP;

   IF p_return_code = 0 THEN

     COMMIT;

   ELSE

     ROLLBACK;

     p_error_msg := 'An unexpected error occurred';

   END IF;
```

EXCEPTION

```
WHEN OTHERS THEN

     ROLLBACK;

     p_error_msg := 'An unexpected error occurred';

     p_return_code := 20;
```

END p_add_project_dates;

Comment: You'll need to use ODP.NET to pass a UDT to a stored proc. Supposedly you can use the Oracle Developer Tools to generate the classes for you. I used examples and coded it up myself. [This article](http://developergeeks.com/article/3/user-defined-type-support-in-oracle-odp-net-11g) may help. I also found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/980421/119477) helpful

Comment: just as an aside using the WHEN OTHERS will come back to haunt you. Best practice is to use the exceptions you expect like NO DATA FOUND and raise everything else.

Comment: Thanks for the links, will check them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the advice.  When I first looked at creating a custom UDT class it looked like it would be a bit of a headache as I wasn't entirely sure what I would have to do inside the class.

Turns out that Visual Studio allows you to create a custom class from the Oracle UDT (as Conrad pointed out) by right clicking on it within the schema (inside server explorer) and selecting "create custom class".  This then opens a wizard which basically does everything for you.

Once I had the custom class I could just create and instance of it and populate the start and end dates of this instance then pass it as a parameter to the stored proc.

Turns out that the procedure I was calling was actually not working properly anyway, so an Oracle dev has been put on the case to fix it.

At least I now know how to create the UDT class.

Thanks again.