# How i insert Sdo_Geometry object in oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-spatial

I am having  SDO_GEOMETRY object variable that fetches sdo_geometry
 type data from map.I must insert geoloc.

I do somthing like this

```
orcl.CommandText = "insert into table1 (id,geoloc) values(:id,:geoloc)";
orcl.SetBindByName(true);
orcl.SetArrayCount(ArrayCount);
orcl.AddParameter(":ID",OracleDbType.Int32,ParameterDirection.Input,Idlist.ToArray());
orcl.AddParameter(":GEOLOC",OracleDbType.Object,ParameterDirection.Input,ObjectList.ToArray());
orcl.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Addparameter  Method

```
public void AddParameter(string parameterName, OracleDbType _type,ParameterDirection dValue, Array _value)
{
   (OracleCommand)cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(parameterName, _type, _value, dValue));
}
```

I am taking this error:

> Invalid parameter binding.  Parameter name: :GEOLOC

How must i do?

Comment: You could try embedding the `SDO_GEOMETRY` object into the SQL and just binding the values that you want to pass into that object: `INSERT INTO table1 ( id, geoloc ) VALUES( :id, SDO_GEOMETRY( 2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(:lat,:long,NULL), NULL, NULL) )`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
However, I need to insert table, regardless of the object type.
So I have to give a parametric array of sdo_geometr objects.

Comment: You passed a List<T> both for the ID and GEOLOC parameters. What is `ObjectList`? Unless it contains UDTs that inherit from IOracleCustomType [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980421/c-pass-a-user-defined-type-to-a-oracle-stored-procedure), Oracle won't understand them. You'd need to create your own UDT like the one [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1105530/134204) or convert your geometry to text, pass it to Oracle as a CLOB parameter and use [FROM_WKTGEOMETRY](SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY) in your query to parse the text to a geometry